# power supply frequency response

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, frequency-measurement, power-electronics, bode-plot

I have a question regarding the frequency response of a boost converter.  I am curious to know what causes the "blip" at around 8kHz that causes the response to go up and then back down.  At first, I thought that perhaps it may be a ESR zero, but thinking more closely, a single zero would not cause the response to rise like that.  Furthermore, the response shows another pole afterwards, and I can't quite see where its coming from either.  Anybody experience this or seen the cause of this before?

[image: bode diagram]
[image: LLC resonant converter]

LLC resonant converter

Comment: Is it possible to share the model schematic?

Comment: 1. Could you show your circuit? 2. In your response plots, what is the stimulus (input voltage, load current, or something else) and what is the response variable (presumably supply output voltage, but please tell us so we'll know)?

Comment: @AnalogArsonist I have edited the post with schematic.

Comment: @ThePhoton The stimulus if switching frequency, the and response variable is output voltage.

Comment: I think this is due to the natural frequency of the system.

Comment: It could be the reflected secondary capacitor (impedance). It would be parallel with the primary, so f0 would be even lower.

Comment: @suzu, can you show us the circuit you actually simulated? Can I assume you put the AC source in front of the primary side inductor?